# Xml.Linq: Add a XNode to a XDocument

Tags: .net, xml, linq

I have to export to XML a list of BusinessObjects - myBOs

I worked before with such a tasks, using XmlDocument.

Now, I read that System.Xml.Linq is more flexible to use. So I took XDocument.

Now the logic is the following (pseudo code):

```
Method ExportBOs(myBOs, fileName) 
  xDoc = New XDocument          ' create
  foreach bo in myBOs
    xDoc.Add(GetMyBOAsNode(bo)) ' build
  xDoc.Save(filename)           ' save


Method GetMyBOAsNode(myBo) as XNode
  result = New XNode(myBo.Name) ' ??? don't work
  Return result
```

What is the way to deal with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems:

- `XNode` is abstract. I suspect you *actually* want to create an `XElement`
- You can't have multiple top-level elements. I suspect you want to create a single root `XElement`, add it to the document, and then add multiple child elements to *that* root element.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to have a single root element (multiple roots are not allowed).

Second, use `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`:

```
public void ExportBOs(IEnumerable<myBO> myBOs, string fileName)
{
    var root = new XElement("BOs");

    foreach(var bo in myBOs){
        root.Add(new XElement("BO", bo.Name));
    }

    root.Save(filePath);
}
```